# Docker-compose up not running

Tags: docker, docker-compose

Having strange problem when running docker container with docker-compose.
It's a docker container with apache+php

If i run it manually - everything ok.

```
[root@opcis proxy-handler]# docker run -itd -v proxy_html:/var/www/html -p 9001:80 --name=webapp-handler2 jaels/proxy-handler
0b217e295e345056308daedaea441d2b123dd05c7cf29d5c219939f557f8374b
[root@opcis proxy-handler]# docker ps
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                 COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
0b217e295e34        jaels/proxy-handler   "/bin/sh -c '/usr/sbi"   6 seconds ago       Up 1 seconds        0.0.0.0:9001->80/tcp   webapp-handler2
```

But if i run it with docker-compose - it fails with "httpd (pid 8) already running"

```
[root@opcis proxy-handler]# cat docker-compose.yml 
version: "2"
services:
        proxy-handler:
                image: jaels/proxy-handler 
                ports:
                        - 9001:80
                volumes:
                        - ./webdata:/var/www/html

[root@opcis proxy-handler]# docker-compose up
Creating proxyhandler_proxy-handler_1
Attaching to proxyhandler_proxy-handler_1
proxy-handler_1  | Passing arguments to httpd using apachectl is no longer supported.
proxy-handler_1  | You can only start/stop/restart httpd using this script.
proxy-handler_1  | If you want to pass extra arguments to httpd, edit the
proxy-handler_1  | /etc/sysconfig/httpd config file.
proxy-handler_1  | httpd (pid 8) already running
proxyhandler_proxy-handler_1 exited with code 0

[root@opcis proxy-handler]# docker-compose ps
            Name                          Command               State    Ports
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
proxyhandler_proxy-handler_1   /bin/sh -c /usr/sbin/apach ...   Exit 0
```

Comment: The image you're using is broken. Contact its maintainer.

Answer (score 0):

See the Dockerfile and run-apache.sh script in [this repository](https://github.com/fedora-cloud/Fedora-Dockerfiles/tree/master/apache). In short, if the httpd process thinks it's already running, then it won't start again. Adding a startup script to the Dockerfile that removes that pid file allows httpd to start.